# Jersey : How to send /pass Custom DTO to a Service class in Jersey

Tags: rest, jersey

I am using Jersey Framework for developing my Webservices. I have a DTO object named UserInfo with setters and getters inside it. I am setting this DTO value initially when the user logs in. How can I pass this user-specific DTO to a Jersey service class?

I have tried setting them inside MultivaluedMap and Form but I was out of luck making it work.

This is my code :

```java
MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
queryParams.add("queryTerm", "userdto");

Form f = new Form();
f.add("name", "1001D");
```

And this is the way I am trying to retrieve the Data.

```java
public class HaiService {
    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public String sayPlainTextHello(@Context UriInfo ui) {

      MultivaluedMap queryParams=ui.getQueryParameters();
      Iterator it=queryParams.keySet().iterator();
      String theKey=null;
      String returnString="";   

      while(it.hasNext()) {
        theKey=(String)it.next();
        System.out.println(queryParams.getFirst(theKey));
      }

      System.out.println("I am called");
      return "Hi";
    }
```

But I was out of luck. Typically my requirement is to store user-specific data on logon,  and then retrive that inside the service class.

I am avoiding storing data in session because a user might login with multiple ID's under one browser, which produces the same session id, and there is a chance of data being overwritten for the first logged in user.

Comment: We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: Did you check this example : [rest Jersey](http://code.google.com/p/restjersey/)

Comment: Thnaks Ali for the link  , but i could any Example there .